# How to make an object global in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I made a little phonegap/cordova application, and I need to access an object inside my .js file. Turns out I have no idea on how to change the structure of my code to make this happen.

Here is my index.html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>NFC tag ID reader</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            // Wait for device API libraries to load
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

            // device APIs are available
            function onDeviceReady() {
                window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
            }
            function gotFS(fileSystem) {
                fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
            }
            function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
                fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
            }

            function gotFileWriter(writer) {
                writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
                    console.log("contents of file now 'some sample text'");
                    writer.truncate(11);
                    writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
                        console.log("contents of file now 'some sample'");
                        writer.seek(4);
                        writer.write(" different text");
                        writer.onwriteend = function(evt){
                            console.log("contents of file now 'some different text'");
                        }
                    };
                };
                writer.write("some sample text");
                //MAKE THIS OBJECT GLOBAL ?
            }

            function fail(error) {
                console.log(error.code);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my index.js code :

```
var app = {
    /* Application constructor */
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
        console.log("Starting NFC Reader app");
    },
    /* bind any events that are required on startup to listeners: */
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    /* this runs when the device is ready for user interaction: */
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        nfc.addTagDiscoveredListener(
            app.onNfc,             // tag successfully scanned
            function (status) {    // listener successfully initialized
                app.displayCpt("<b>"+cpt+"</b>" + ' personnes restantes.');
                app.displayBjr("\n");
                app.displayBjr("Identifiez-vous:");
            },
            function (error) {     // listener fails to initialize
                app.display("NFC reader failed to initialize " +
                JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        );
    },
    /* displays tag ID from @nfcEvent in message div: */

    onNfc: function(nfcEvent) {
    var tag = nfcEvent.tag;
    var nfcUid = nfc.bytesToHexString(tag.id);
    var myDb = {
        "04c85ccab52880": {
            "name": "name",
            "firstname": "fname",
            "societe": "work"
        }
        var mapped = Object.keys(myDb).map(function(uid){
            return (myDb[uid].uid = uid) && myDb[uid];
        });

        for(var i = 0; i < mapped.length ; i++){
            if(mapped[i]['uid'] != nfcUid){
                mapped[i]['uid'] += 1;
            } else {
                mapped[i]['uid'] = nfcUid;
                app.display(mapped[i]['name'] + ' ' + mapped[i]['firstname'] + ', ' + mapped[i]['societe']);
                writer.write(mapped[i]['name'] + ' ' + mapped[i]['firstname'] + ', ' + mapped[i]['societe']);
                //I WOULD NEED THIS WRITER USABLE IN ORDER TO WRITE MY ARRAY CONTENT INTO A FILE
            }
        }

    },

};     // end of app
```

I think my `writer` object needs to be global in order to make the mapped array write into a file, but I can't find a way to do that.. Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting `var writer` outside of everything and removing it from the arguments list of `gotFileWriter(writer)`? That should make it a global variable. Note that this isn't exactly the best of programming practices, one should avoid global variables where possible.

Comment: Hi Revan, what `var writer` are you talking about ? I don't have any `var writer` in my code so far, that is why I can't put it outside of the code ...

Comment: @FlorentP No, what you need to do is make a `var writer` outside of any functions or objects (I'd suggest after `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);`)  and then turn `gotFileWriter(writer)` into `gotFileWriter()`. That should turn your `writer` variable into a global object.

Comment: Is that going to make `writer` usable in my .js file ?

Comment: It should if you include your .js file **after** your other script. If you don't want to move the .js file, you can put `var writer` at the beginning of it instead.

Comment: Arf .. I tried to do this way, but it seems to be not working.

Comment: @FlorentP If you tried both ways, then I'm not exactly sure how to fix the problem.